# MySQL: Insert if foreign key exists

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

I have an Excel sheet with around 2.000 rows that I want to insert into my database.

The problem is that the table I want to insert the 2.000 rows into has a column that references to a foreign key in another table. Unfortunately a lot of queries fail, since the provided foreign key value does NOT exist.

I know that I can ignore foreign key checks, but this is not what I want. I don't want to ignore foreign key checks, I just want bad queries not to be executed.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, value) VALUES (10, 20);  
INSERT INTO test (id, value) VALUES (20, 20);
```

The first query fails, since `TEST.id` references `foobar.id` and there is no `foobar.id = 10.` However, the second query would work, since `foobar.id = 20` exists, but the second query won't be executed, because the first one already failed.

Is there any way I don't get an error on the first query and my other queries will still be executed?

I could write a php script, but I'd prefer a MySQL solution here.

Answer (score 7):

You could change to insert the result of a select, so something like:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, value) 
SELECT foobar.id, 20
FROM foobar WHERE id = 10;
```

Comment: Have to add limit 1, otherwise each insert could be multiple rows.

Comment: @MJB I'm assuming that id is the primary key on `foobar`, per the OP, so the `LIMIT` *shouldn't* be needed.

Comment: If I do it like that, it's only possible to insert data into "test", which is already in "foobar", right? But I have new data to add, which comes from the excel sheet. 

Can i somehow adjust this, so i can add new data to it?

Comment: I mis-read.  I think you are right, and I retract my comment.

Comment: @snootles Have you the information to create the record in `foobar`? If so you could instead pre-create the values, perhaps using a query along the lines of `INSERT INTO foobar (id,...) SELECT 10, ... FROM test LEFT JOIN foobar ON test.id = foobar.id WHERE foobar.id IS NULL`