# Query foreign keys on insert statement (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

If I want to simultaneously find a primary key and use it as a foreign key on an insert statement, then I can use the below query (found it here at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117734/mysql-insert-if-foreign-key-exists))

```
INSERT INTO test (id, value) 
SELECT foobar.id, 20
FROM foobar WHERE name = 'joe';
```

But what if I want to insert more than one foreign key? How would the statement look?

```
INSERT INTO test (id1, id2, id3, value) 
SELECT foobar1.id, foobar2.id, foobar3.id, 20
FROM foobar1 WHERE name = 'joe'
FROM foobar2 WHERE name = 'joe'
FROM foobar3 WHERE name = 'joe';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?:

```
INSERT INTO test ( id1, id2, id3, value ) 
SELECT 
foobar1.id, foobar2.id, foobar3.id, 20
FROM 
foobar1, foobar2, foobar3
WHERE 
foobar1.name = 'joe'
AND 
foobar2.name = 'joe'
AND 
foobar2.name = 'joe';
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Is SupremeDud's answer better worse? He took a different approach

Comment: Do you want the rows to look like "id1, id2, id3, value"? If so, then mine will work. If you want the row to just be "id, value", then SupremeDud's.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO test (id1, id2, id3, value) 
SELECT foobar1.id, foobar2.id, foobar3.id, 20
FROM foobar1,foobar2, foobar3
WHERE foobar1.name = 'joe'
AND foobar2.name = 'joe'
AND foobar3.name = 'joe';
```

Comment: sorry, I want one row with multiple columns